# Trouble access load balancing acl haproxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, apache2

I got some trouble in load balancer using haproxy.
Why acl **rndbackend** accessed **kindevbackend** ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JED0.jpg

Here's my host setting
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXHu8.jpg

When I try using curl -v rndbackend.local, it successfull and like my hope
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPewB.jpg

[update]

this is my virtual host
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPQs5.png

But why when I accessed rndback.com it accessed kindev.my.id?
How to solve this ?

Thank you for attention

Comment: This looks more like a configuration issue on the backend.  Show the vhost config - do you have a vhost for `rndback.com` configured on each backend?

Comment: yes of course. wait ya

Comment: please check @tetech

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a vhost for `rndback.com`.

If there's no matching vhost then in an all-vhost config you will be directed to the first one, and `kindev.conf` is loaded before `rndback.conf` (alphabetically).

The answer is to create a vhost for `rndback.com` (or put it as a `ServerAlias` in `rndback.conf`).

Comment: thank you very much, this issue has solved with different port